# Cycles of Permutation Related to Rectangular Matrix Transposition

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, computational-complexity, permutations

let the entries of a rectangular matrix $A\in\mathbb{C}^{m\times n}; m,n\in\mathbb{N}$ be stored in row-order in a linear vector $v$, i.e. $A_{i,j}=v_{i*m+j}$

**Question:**
How can the first element and the size of the next cycle in the permutation $\mathcal{P}(v_i)$ of the entries of $v$ be calculated, when $\mathcal{P}(v_i)$ represents the transpose $A^T\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times m}$ of $A$, i.e. when $A^T_{rs}=\mathcal{P}(v_i)_{n*r+s}$?

Background of the question is to calculate the matrix transpose with a minimal number of assignments and only one additional temporary value.
If for example a cycle were $(a,b,c)$, then using the extra variable $t$, the part of the permutation related to the cycle could be calculated as $t:=a; a:=b; b:=c; c:=t;$

Being able to calculate the first element and the size of the cycles is important to avoid having to remember the elements that already have been permuted.
By *the first element of the next cycle* I mean the entry of $v$ with the smallest index, that has not yet been permuted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the paper "**In-Place Transposition of Rectangular Matrices**" by **Fred G. Gustavson and Tadeusz Swirszcz**, which provides a solution for the problem.

An online version of the paper can be found here:
http://www.orcca.on.ca/conferences/cca2008/papers/gustavson.pdf